# Android Kotlin Room Type Converter for JSON Array

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, typeconverter

I know there's a lot of other post regarding type converter, but I am facing a different scenario here.
What's different is actually the Json format that I am receiving from my server, and I cant ask them to update their format just so I can fix this issue.

I know Im just missing something or just doing it wrong 
Here's my sample Json format

```
[{"name":"John","age":30,"cars":["Ford","BMW","Fiat"]}]
```

The cars format is not object, but JSON Array, and I kinda want to store it under List format in Kotlin

```
@Entity(tableName = "person")
data class Person(

    @PrimaryKey
    var name: String,

    var age: Int,

    @SerializedName("cars")
    @TypeConverters(ListTypeConverter::class)
    var cars: Array<Car>

)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks all

Comment: `val cars: List<String>` not work?

Comment: @GianhTran not working, Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line

Comment: show your POJO class, please

Comment: got it, please check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your POJO it not correct, check below one

```
   @Entity(tableName = "person")
    data class Person(

        @PrimaryKey
        var name: String,

        var age: Int,

        @SerializedName("cars")
        @TypeConverters(ListTypeConverter::class)
        var cars: Array<String>
    )
```

`cars` is a list of String, not Object

Comment: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.

Comment: Ah sorry for removing that LOC.

Comment: I just tweak something on the type converter, and it worked with your answer, thanks man ! I appreciate your help, Ill upvote this as token. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
var cars = mutableListOf<String>()
```

then add JSONArray data inside it

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to the guidelines on how to contribute. It is required that you give an explanation to your answer with the help of a well-documented code snippet.